# Oracle Query to select separate numbers and special characters

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, translate

I am writing a query to separate numbers and special character.

```
 SELECT distinct TO_NUMBER(NVL(TRANSLATE(RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS_SV.SELL_FORMULA,'DGP*$null','0'),0)) FROM RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS_SV ;
```

this is giving the below error:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:
*Action:

I want the output to be number. But its giving me error. Initially i thought it was because of nulls so i used nvl to replace by zeroes still it is not working.
This is just to extract numbers i want to write one more query to extract alphabets and characters from the same field?

Comment: What data is in the field - I'm guessing three are some characters other than `DGP*$ 0`... Not sure what you mean by "extract", do you mean you want 2 columns, one with all numbers and one with all alphas?

Comment: yes the values are in this manner D.70, GP44, *0.552, $4.03 etc

Comment: and i want to 2 columns one with number and one with characters. also is there any way to avoid hardcoding i have done?

Comment: Run `SELECT TRANSLATE(RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS_SV.SELL_FORMULA,'DGP*$','0') FROM RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS_SV;` to see what values might be tripping up the `TO_NUMBER`.

Comment: some of the fields are null and so i think i am getting the invalid number error.

Comment: I am still not getting the alphanumeric part separately.. Can anyone help?